# How to test element onClick function with cypress on react?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, cypress

I have a component which, when clicked, it expands and shows more information. I'm trying to test that action of expanding when I click at the component, but cypress returns me code error but there's no code error when running on development and testing by myself.

My attempt was click the component, and check if the new information appears, if so, then it would be the correct behavior.

Component:

```
...


export const MaterialCard: React.FC<IMaterialCard> = ({ material }) => {

  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState<boolean>(false)

  return (

    *<Container data-cy='container' onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)} style={isExpanded ? { maxWidth: 635 } : { maxWidth: 320 }}>*


        {isExpanded && (
          <>
            <Row style={{ marginTop: 16 }}>
              <Col><h6 style={{ color: "#606060", fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 700 }}>Ementa</h6></Col>
            </Row>
            <Row style={{ marginTop: 16 }}>
              <Col >
                <span style={{ fontSize: 14, color: "#333" }}>
                  {material.resume}
                </span>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row style={{ marginTop: 16 }}>
              <Col style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                *<Link data-cy='toDetail' to={'/detail'} >Ver material completo</Link>*
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </>

        )}
    </Container>
```

Test:

```
describe('Material Card', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.mount(<MaterialCard material={material} />)
  })

  it('should expand when clicked', () => {

    cy.get('[data-cy=container]').click()
    cy.get('[data-cy=toDetail]').should('have.text', 'Ver material completo')
  })
  
})
```

Error:

The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.

> Invariant failed

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.